# How to unmarshal a schema based request result correctly (i.e. xwiki)?

Tags: java, xml, rest, jaxb, xwiki

I used the [XWiki Schema Definition](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-rest/xwiki-platform-rest-model/src/main/resources/xwiki.rest.model.xsd) to create with the Eclipse XJC Binding Compiler an object class model. In the **package-info.java** the following namespace is created

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.xwiki.org", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package org.xwiki.rest.model.jaxb;
```

When i read an [Example from an HttpResponse](http://www.file-upload.net/download-8973539/request_result.xml.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<page xmlns="http://www.xwiki.org">
   <link rel="http://www.xwiki.org/rel/space" href="http://localhost:8080/xwiki/rest/wikis/xwiki/spaces/Main" />
   ...
</page>
```

with JAXB

```
try {
   JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(org.xwiki.rest.model.jaxb.Page.class);
   Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
   InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("request_result.xml"));
   Page page = (Page) unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
} catch (JAXBException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the Exception

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.xwiki.org", local:"page"). Expected elements are <{http://www.xwiki.org}attachments>,<{http://www.xwiki.org}classes>,<{http://www.xwiki.org}comments>,<{http://www.xwiki.org}history>,<{http://www.xwiki.org}objects>,<{http://www.xwiki.org}pages>,<{http://www.xwiki.org}properties>,<{http://www.xwiki.org}searchResults>,<{http://www.xwiki.org}spaces>,<{http://www.xwiki.org}tags>,<{http://www.xwiki.org}wikis>
   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:648)
   at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:236)
   ...
```

is thrown.

I don't understand what's wrong, because the namespace seems correct. What i have to change to get a working XWiki RESTful API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping for the `page` element is probably on an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation on the generated `ObjectFactory` class.  You could change your `JAXBContext` creation to the following to pick that up:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(org.xwiki.rest.model.jaxb.ObjectFactory.class);
```

Or you could just create the `JAXBContext` on the package name of the generated model:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("org.xwiki.rest.model.jaxb");
```

---

### UPDATE

> Thanks, that helped a little. Now i get Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be
>   cast to org.xwiki.rest.model.jaxb.Page.

The result you get when the root is annotated with `@XmlElementDecl` instead of `@XmlRootElement` is an instance of `JAXBElement` that contains an instance of the domain class.

You can do the following:

```
JAXBElement<Page> jaxbElement = (JAXBElement<Page>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(is);
Page page = jaxbElement.getValue();
```

Or:

```
Page page = (Page) JAXBIntrospector.getValue(unmarshaller.unmarshal(is));
```

**For More Information**

I have written more about this particular use case on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html

Comment: Thanks, that helped a little. Now i get _Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast to org.xwiki.rest.model.jaxb.Page_. I put the class at http://www.file-upload.net/download-8975023/Page.java.html. The Object Factory is here http://www.file-upload.net/download-8975019/ObjectFactory.java.html